# How to implement a password change functionality with Oracle and a .Net client?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I'm using Oracle users to authenticate username and password for a .Net application. Right now I'm working on the password change function. The database has a custom password validation, so if you try to change a users password and you provide an invalid password, Oracle returns multiple errors.

The first error is always "ORA-28003: password verification for the specified password failed", and then it rises one error for each failed validation. This is shown correctly when I try to change a user's password from the Toad client.

However, when I do this from my application, the OracleException that is raised only returns the first error, and therefore I'm not able to show the user what's invalid about the new password he provided, which is a requirement for the application. So how should I aproach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, don't use the OpenWithNewPassword method.  Not only does it have known issues with with various versions of ODP.net and the DB, but it forces you to have two different branches of code when you only need one - IIRC it doesn't work if the user's password has already expired.

Instead the basic logic works like this:

- Make sure you can authenticate with the user's old account and password
- If you're successful, close that connection and open a separate account that has no access other than exec privs on a ChangePassword stored procedure.

Here's the code:

```
protected void BtnChangePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  String connectionStringFormat = "Data Source={0};User Id={1};Password={2};pooling=false;";
  if (Page.IsValid)
  {
    Boolean hasHasError = false;
    String connectionString = String.Format(
      connectionStringFormat,
      IptDatabase.Text,
      IptUserName.Text,
      IptOldPassword.Text);
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    using (cmd.Connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
      try
      {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
      }
      catch (OracleException ex)
      {
        //allow to continue if the password is simply expired, otherwise just show the message
        if (ex.Number != 28001)
        {
          ShowErrorMessage(ex.Message);
          hasHasError = true;
        }
      }

      if (!hasHasError)
      {
        //successful authentication, open as password change account
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[IptDatabase.Text].ConnectionString;
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SysChangePassword";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("username", IptUserName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("newpassword", IptPassword.Text);
        try
        {
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          ShowInfoMessage("Password Changed");
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
          ShowErrorMessage(ex.Message);
        }


      }
    }
  }
```

In it's simplest form, the proc executes 'alter user identified by and would be similar to the one documented here: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/change_password.html.  However the dbms_output lines don't do you much good so you could throw custom exceptions instead:

```
create or replace procedure SysChangePassword(
  pUserName in varchar2, 
  pPassWord in Varchar2) as
begin
  -- Check for system users here and reject
  if upper(pUserName) in ('SYS','SYSTEM') then
            raise_application_error(-20012, 'not allowed');
  else
     execute immediate 'alter user '||pUserName||' identified by ' ||
           pPassWord;
  end if;
  exception --this isn't necessary if you'd rather examine and handle the specific exceptions on the .net side
     when others then
        raise_application_error(-20012, sqlerrm);
end;
/
```

The schema that owns this procedure needs 'alter any user' privleges.  For safety's sake, your app should connect as a separate user that only has execute privs on this proc.  Rather

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you wrap the logic in a stored procedure?  It would call the Oracle password validation functions, then you parse the results as needed, and return whatever messages you want back to the .net client?

Comment: This is definetly a possibility, and it was considered. But the thing is, the user needs to be allowed to change his password when his account has expired. Right now, it's using the LoginWithDiffrentPassowrd() method from the oracle connection, which allows just that. But in order to use a stored procedure to change the password, the user should be logged in, which he can't.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a Regular Expression Validator control if writing for ASP.NET, Or Regex.IsMatch(...) Function if writing desktop applications? Why you have to go to the server first to get the error generated. you have strong password policy, and you can restrict the user on client side.

Comment: Why should the OP re-invent the wheel and re-implement a working policy in C#? There might be other applications connecting to the database - how would you prevent users from changing their passwords to something insecure in these applications ?

Comment: For one, this database is accesed by a number of systems developed by difrent teams from difrent companies, so the username and password validation shouldn't be controlled by the application.

Also, the client wants to be able to change the validation function at leisure without having to rewrite any code or configuration file in the application.

Comment: Can you paste the Stack Trace from the exception you get after running the application in Debug mode from VS? Don't you get InnerException property?